# Java regex for function call

Tags: java, regex, function

I'm working to turn this current regex statement to only accept two string arguments (right now it accepts an unlimited number of arguments), but I'm a little confused.  Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
^\s*test_function\((['"])(.+?)\2\);?\s*$
```

Examples of valid input include:

```
test_function('ab', 'cd')
test_function('120abcd', '1209sfdlc')
test_function('fslkf,z', 'sldkfj129')
test_function("hi", "hello")
```

Comment: can you give us some inputs?

Comment: Is `test_function("ab", "cd")` a valid input?

Comment: As with everything else, I start with a unit test. You will need to write some test strings you want to pass and some you don't, then run against this regex. Once you've got your tests written, you can show us what you're doing.

Comment: Is `test_function("a,b","b,c")` a valid call?

Comment: got it, I'll add them in just a minute!

Comment: Is `test_function("a,b",obj)` a valid call? where `obj` is a `String` object reference.

Comment: no it cannot be an object reference!

Comment: you can't use single quotes for string in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to restrict your function to accept 2 string parameters only (wrapped in single or double quote)

```
^\s*test_function\((['"])([^'"]*)\1 *, *(['"])([^'"]*)\3\);?\s*$
```

And use captured groups `#2` and `#4` for your function arguments.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD1iL2/3)

Comment: single quotes is not allowed for String value in Java. single quotes is used for single character only.

Comment: Yes that I know but we don't know if these input strings are indeed valid Java code.

Comment: the inputs are from a web interface, so yes single quotes should be allowed in this expression, thanks!

Comment: What about `test_function("ab', 'cd')` ?

Comment: @Betlista: That does not look like a valid function? Since opening double quote has a closing single quote.

Comment: @Betlista - that is not a valid statement, the reason we are collecting input in this way is that its more familiar for our users to type and understand - in Javascript like syntax

Comment: the regexp marks this `test_function('a," b' , "b,c")` as invalid, same with `test_function("a,' b" , "b,c")` and in Java also `test_function("a,\" b" , "b,c")` is valid...

Comment: @Betlista: OP hasn't given any requirement of nested quotes OR escaped quotes. If that is there you can use this more complex regex: `^\s*test_function\((['"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1 *, *(['"])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3\);?\s*$` or [see this demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD1iL2/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
            test_function\(\s*"[^"]+"\s*,\s*"[^"]+"\s*\)
First argument ----------------^^^^          ^^^^-------- Second argument
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL7nZ8/1)

---

If single quote is also valid input then try

```
test_function\(\s*(["'])[^\1]+?\1\s*,\s*(["'])[^\2]+?\2\s*\)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL7nZ8/3)

Comment: it marks `test_function("a"b", "cd")` as valid match?

Comment: @Betlista Have you tested it in both the demo? By the way it should be `test_function("a\"b", "cd")`

Comment: not in both, in second, but maybe I did'n understand the output, for `test_function("a"b", "cd")` and `test_function("ab", "cd")` output is the same, so matched?